# React - State not updated or getting reset to old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onkeyup

I am trying to build a chat application with the functionality of input field which can be used as filter for chat_groups array which is in the state as **chat_groups**. Here is how my code looks:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currUserId: "--id--",
      chats: [],
      chat_groups: [],
      users: [],
    };
  }
  .
  .
  .
  <input
className="chat-group__search__input"
placeholder="Search for group..."
onChange={(ev) => {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.value);
    var thatState = this.state;
    thatState.chat_groups = thatState.chat_groups.map(
    (gp) => {
        gp["visible"] = gp.group_name
        .toLowerCase()
        .includes(ev.currentTarget.value);
        return gp;
    }
    );
    // getting correct state in thatState variable
    this.setState(thatState);
}}
/>
// getting old state in setState callback and componentDidUpdate lifecycle
```

The weird problem is I am getting the correct value in thatState variable before setting state. But after setState function is called, if I try to check the state in setState callback or componentDidUpdate lifecycle, I am getting the old state only.

I tried that for keydown and change events also. So, seems to be less of an issue of event as well.

I would like to know if some issue in the code is evident or there is something that I can do to debug the issue.

**Edit:** After changes, my current onChange looks as below, but the issue is still there; the setState function does not seem to change the state as I can see only the old state in componentDidUpdate lifecycle and setState callback.

```
 onChange={(ev) => {
                      console.log(ev.currentTarget.value);
                      let chat_groups = this.state.chat_groups.map((gp) => ({
                        ...gp,
                        visible: gp.group_name
                          .toLowerCase()
                          .includes(ev.currentTarget.value),
                      }));
                      console.log(
                        "Before",
                        chat_groups.map((gp) => gp.visible)
                      );
                      this.setState({ chat_groups: chat_groups });
                    }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are mutating the `state`.

When you do `var thatState = this.state;` the reference is still the same for both the objects. So automatically when you update `thatState.chat_groups` you are updating/mutating `state` as well.

Change your `onChange` method to like below

```
onChange = ev => {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget.value);
  let { chat_groups } = this.state;
  chat_groups = chat_groups.map(gp => ({
      ...gp,
      visible: gp.group_name.toLowerCase().includes(ev.currentTarget.value)
  }));

  this.setState(state => ({
    ...state,
    chat_groups
  }));
};
//Other code
//....
//....
<input
  className="chat-group__search__input"
  placeholder="Search for group..."
  onChange={this.onChange} />
```

I suspect there's one problem while checking the `group_name` with the input value i.e., you are converting the `group_name` to `lower case` using `gp.group_name.toLowerCase()` but the input value you are not converting to `lower case`. This could be one issue why the `visible` attribute value is not getting updated. So in the below snippet I have converted the input value also to `lower case` while comparing.

Here, below is a runnable snippet with your requirement. Doing `console.log` in the `setState`'s callback function and the state is getting updated.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currUserId: "--id--",
      chats: [],
      chat_groups: [{
        group_name: "Group One"
      }, {
        group_name: "Group Two"
      }],
      users: []
    }
  }

  onChange = ev => {
    console.log(ev.currentTarget.value);
    let {
      chat_groups
    } = this.state;
    chat_groups = chat_groups.map(gp => ({
      ...gp,
      visible: gp.group_name.toLowerCase().includes(ev.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase())
    }));
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      chat_groups
    }), () => { console.log(this.state.chat_groups); });
  };
  
  render() {
    return <input 
      placeholder="Search for group..."
      onChange={this.onChange} />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: You are still mutating the state. Check this line `gp['visible'] = gp.group_name ` line, this references to the same object in the state.

Comment: Thanks but after these changes also, it is not working.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: I have updated the new onChange in the question. The problem is still the same; before setState is called, I am getting the changes in the visible attribute of each chat group, but after setState, I am getting the old state again (checking from the componentDidUpdate lifecycle and setState callback).

Comment: I have updated my answer with the runnable snippet, please have a look once. Hoping that this will help.

Comment: @Nithish thanks a lot, but I am still facing the same issue. please let me know if you are available for a screenshare on google meet or zoom so that you can see the code and try to figure out what is going wrong. only if you are available. Because code looks all fine and everything seems to be perfect, but this still is not working good. :/

Comment: Yeah sure. No problem

Answer (score 0):

No, don't do this `var thatState = this.state` it's just an object it will easily get mutate and you will not get the update as for react state change never occured.

instead do this `var { chat_groups } = this.state` and then use it further and inlast set the state `this.setState({ chat_groups: chat_groups })` also try to avoid the mutation as much as possible means copy the values of  `chat_groups` also

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are trying to manipulate state directly which is a big no in React.

```
onChange={(ev) => {
    this.setState({
        chat_groups: this.state.chat_groups.map((gp) => {
            gp["visible"] = gp.group_name
            .toLowerCase()
            .includes(ev.currentTarget.value);
            return gp;
        })
    });
}}
```

Comment: This line would still mutate the state directly `gp["visible"] = gp.group_name`

Comment: Oh yeah you are right.
You would have to make a clone first

Comment: Thanks but after these changes also, it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**State should only be updated using the [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly) method.**

You are mutating the state directly in your code above - [this isn't recommended](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly). You would get unexpected results and it's not predictable.

This is how you should do it - create a new updated object and pass it to the `setState`.

```js
onChange={(ev) => {
  console.log(ev.currentTarget.value);

  const updatedChatGroups = this.state.chat_groups.map((gp) => {
    const visible = gp.group_name.toLowerCase().includes(ev.currentTarget.value);

    return {
      ...gp,
      visible,
    };
  });

  // Update the modified object using this.setState().
  this.setState({ chat_groups: updatedChatGroups });
}}
```

[**Read More**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)

Comment: Thanks but after these changes also, it is not working. still the state after setState is the old state.